# inequality, complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, mathematica

let $b>0$, $y:[0,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and $y(0)=0$, where $\mathbb{C}$ denotes the space of complex numbers.
Is the following inequality true or not? 
$$|y(x)|\le \max_{\tau\in[0,b]} |y'(\tau)| \cdot b$$

Please notes that $y(x)$ is not a real function. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking. Also, it appears you've used $x$ to denote different things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. Since Wikipedia does a good job of explaining it in the general case (here $\Bbb C$ isn't much different from $\Bbb R^2$), I'll contend myself to linking to the [relevant part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions) on the Mean Value theorem page (see equation (**)).